# Problems matching a string to a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, remote-host

I am creating some intranet software and to determine which room number and PC number the computer is in I am using the REMOTE_HOST server array.

Here is my code:

```
$hostname = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
//Check to see if the computer name is compatible with room auto-detect
if (preg_match("/G|F\d{1,2}-.*?-PC\d{1,2}.*?/i", $hostname)) {
    $room = explode("-", $hostname);
    $pc = explode(".", $room[2]);
} else {
    $pc[0] = "NA";
    $room[0] = "other";
}
```

This statment needs to be true if the computer names are something like these:

- `g22-dell-pc23.roundhay.local`
- `f48-lenovo-pc02.roundhay.local`
- `g6-asus-pc18.roundhay.local`

If the statement is not as above then it needs to revert the room and pc array to NA and Other.

I can extract the room number and PC successfully but when a PC with a non standard name uses the software it still tries to extract the information and the software fails because it has no information to go on.

For example:

> g22-smartboard.roundhay.local

The software still tries to get the PC number, even though it dosent match my regular expression. However on my testing PC with the computer name JOSH-PC it does fall back onto the default information.

I have tested my regular expression and it seems to be true whenever the name starts with either a G or an F.

I need it to match specifically to these requirements:

- First letter is G or F
- Then either one or two digits from 0 - 9
- Then a -
- Then any amount of letters a-z
- Then a -
- Then the letters PC
- Then either one or two digits from 0 - 9
- Then anything

I have tried all sorts to get this to work but I just don't understand regex properly. I have looked it up but its just all too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression:

```
/[g|f]\d{1,2}-[a-z]+-pc\d{1,2}.+/i
```

Should work. I use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to build expressions.

Comment: Wont the `()` create captures? And add to his array?

Comment: @Cjueden edited. Been a while since I've used a RegExp this complicated. College work really makes you forget things. :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegEx `[G|F]\d{1,2}-[a-z]+-pc\d{1,2}.+`

Also a great resource for regex is http://gskinner.com/RegExr/